# Leer XML complejo con PHP

Tags: php, xml

Buen Día, tengo un archivo XML el cual tengo dificultades para leerlo, mi problema es en las etiquetas, ya que no son etiquetas simples, las Maestras empiezas por cfdi y las que tienen internamente empiezas con ecb, que son las que me interesa obtener su contenido, ya he intentado por varios métodos, pero no tengo éxito, espero me puedan ayudar, soy nuevo en XML, saludos
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <cfdi:Comprobante Version="3.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">

    <cfdi:Complemento>
      <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/......." Version="1.1" UUID="123" FechaTimbrado="123" RfcProvCertif="123" SelloCFD="123"  />
    </cfdi:Complemento>

    <cfdi:Addenda>
      <ecb:EstadoDeCuentaBancario xmlns:ecb="http://schemas.reachcore.com/addendas/addenda-ecb/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.reachcore.com/........ http://go.reachcore.com/......." version="1.0">
        <ecb:Movimientos>
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="123" referencia="123" descripcion="123" importe="123" moneda="123" saldoAlCorte="123" />
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="123" referencia="123" descripcion="123" importe="123" moneda="123" saldoAlCorte="123" />
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="123" referencia="123" descripcion="123" importe="123" moneda="123" saldoAlCorte="123" />
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="123" referencia="123" descripcion="123" importe="123" moneda="123" saldoAlCorte="123" />
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="123" referencia="123" descripcion="123" importe="123" moneda="123" saldoAlCorte="123" />
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="123" referencia="123" descripcion="123" importe="123" moneda="123" saldoAlCorte="123" />
        </ecb:Movimientos>
      </ecb:EstadoDeCuentaBancario>
    </cfdi:Addenda>
  </cfdi:Comprobante>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $xml = <<<EOD
   -- Texto XML-- 
  EOD;
  $dom = new DOMDocument;
  $dom->loadXML($xml);
  foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagNameNS('*', '*') as $element){
    echo 'local name: ', $element->localName, ', prefix: ', $element->prefix,"\n";
  }
?>
```

Hasta ahorita con éste código he podido obtener las etiquetas, pero no el contenido de cada `<ecb:MovimientoECB>` saludos y gracias por su tiempo y ayuda

Comment: Le recomiendo este proyecto para resolver el [parseo de XML Schemas](https://github.com/moyarada/XSD-to-PHP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mira este ejemplo:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$xml="";
try{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($strContenidoXML);
}catch(Exception $e){
    //aqui maneja el error
}
$noNodosRet =  count($xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Retenciones/cfdi:Retencion"));//extrae el numero de nodos retencion
$arrayImporteRetV32 =$xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Retenciones/cfdi:Retencion/@importe");//Xpath que saca los importes V32
$arrayImpuestoRetV32=$xml->xpath("/cfdi:Comprobante/cfdi:Impuestos/cfdi:Retenciones/cfdi:Retencion/@impuesto");//Xpath que saca los impuestos V32
for($i=0;$i<$noNodosRet;$i++){
    $valorImporteRet =  "".trim($arrayImporteRetV32[$i]->importe);
    $valorImpuestoRet =  "".trim($arrayImpuestoRetV32[$i]->impuesto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <cfdi:Comprobante Version="3.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">

    <cfdi:Complemento>
      <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/......." Version="1.1" UUID="123" FechaTimbrado="123" RfcProvCertif="123" SelloCFD="123"  />
    </cfdi:Complemento>

    <cfdi:Addenda>
      <ecb:EstadoDeCuentaBancario xmlns:ecb="http://schemas.reachcore.com/addendas/addenda-ecb/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.reachcore.com/........ http://go.reachcore.com/......." version="1.0">
        <ecb:Movimientos>
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="fecha1" referencia="referencia1" descripcion="descripcion1" importe="importe1" moneda="moneda1" saldoAlCorte="saldoAlCorte1" />
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="fecha2" referencia="referencia2" descripcion="descripcion2" importe="importe2" moneda="moneda2" saldoAlCorte="saldoAlCorte2" />
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="fecha3" referencia="referencia3" descripcion="descripcion3" importe="importe3" moneda="moneda3" saldoAlCorte="saldoAlCorte3" />
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="fecha4" referencia="referencia4" descripcion="descripcion4" importe="importe4" moneda="moneda4" saldoAlCorte="saldoAlCorte4" />
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="fecha5" referencia="referencia5" descripcion="descripcion5" importe="importe5" moneda="moneda5" saldoAlCorte="saldoAlCorte5" />
          <ecb:MovimientoECB fecha="fecha6" referencia="referencia6" descripcion="descripcion6" importe="importe6" moneda="moneda6" saldoAlCorte="saldoAlCorte6" />
        </ecb:Movimientos>
      </ecb:EstadoDeCuentaBancario>
    </cfdi:Addenda>
  </cfdi:Comprobante>
XML;

$factura = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$namespaces = $factura -> getNamespaces(true);
$factura -> registerXPathNamespace('e', $namespaces['ecb']);

foreach ($factura -> xpath('//e:MovimientoECB') as $m) {
    echo($m['fecha']." <br/>");
    echo($m['referencia']." <br/>");
    echo($m['descripcion']." <br/>");
    echo($m['importe']." <br/>");
    echo($m['moneda']." <br/>");
    echo($m['saldoAlCorte']." <br/>");
}
?>
```